# Add watermark image in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have code to add watermark in image like this

```
public static Bitmap mark(Bitmap src, String watermark, Point location, Color color, int alpha, int size, boolean underline) {
            int w = src.getWidth();
            int h = src.getHeight();
            Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, src.getConfig());

            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);
            canvas.drawBitmap(src, 0, 0, null);

            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setColor(color.RED);
            paint.setAlpha(alpha);
            paint.setTextSize(size);
            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            paint.setUnderlineText(underline);
            canvas.drawText(watermark, location.x, location.y, paint);

            return result;
        }
```

and I call that function with this code

```
mark(bitmap, "watermark", b, null, c, 100, false);
            imgshoot.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

but nothing happen , can u help me ?? thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

it solved , I just change little for that code , and thanks for ur advice Doomsknight :)

```
 public static Bitmap mark(Bitmap src, String watermark) {
    int w = src.getWidth();
    int h = src.getHeight();
    Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, src.getConfig());
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);
    canvas.drawBitmap(src, 0, 0, null);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    paint.setTextSize(18);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setUnderlineText(true);
    canvas.drawText(watermark, 20, 25, paint);

    return result;
}
```

and I call with this function

```
bitmap = mark(bitmap, "Hallo");
imgshoot.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not assigning your returned bitmap `result` to anything. Replace the old bitmap with the new one.

```
 bitmap = mark(bitmap, "watermark", b, null, c, 100, false);
 imgshoot.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

EDIT:

as per comments, you are still having issues: Try hardcoding some params, to test. To see if its issues with your params.

```
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(color.RED);
        //paint.setAlpha(alpha);
        paint.setTextSize(20); //size
        //paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setUnderlineText(underline);
        canvas.drawText(watermark, 10, 10, paint); //location.x, location.y
```

Comment: @yaLya See my edit. It is definate that your code must include the first bit. But you seem to have two issues. Try hard coding the params as I have. to see what happens. If this works, inspect your params, and see which one is faulty. :)

Comment: sorry , but nothing happen too , meaby my code to watermark image is wrong :(

Answer (score 1):

```
private Bitmap addWaterMark(Bitmap src) 
{
    int w = src.getWidth();
    int h = src.getHeight();
    Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(w,h,src.getConfig());
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);
    canvas.drawBitmap(src,0,0, null);
    Bitmap waterMark = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_laucher);
    canvas.drawBitmap(waterMark,0,0,null);

    return result;
}
```